# Why does ReactDOM.flushSync not work in Chrome after opening the print dialog

Tags: reactjs, printing

I have a component that calls the following method passing in true inside `window.onbeforeprint` and then calls again passing in false inside `window.onafterprint`.  The method it calls is

```
    updatePrint(print) {
      this.setState({print});
      ReactDOM.flushSync(() => {
        this.forceUpdate();
      });
    }
```

It's called in the component's constructor:

```
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.printMatcher = window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('print');
      window.onbeforeprint = () => {
        this.updatePrint(true);
      };
      window.onafterprint = () => {
        this.updatePrint(false);
      };
      this.state = {print: this.printMatcher && !!this.printMatcher.matches};
    }
```

In Chrome I get the error `Invariant Violation: flushSync was called from inside a lifecycle method. It cannot be called when React is already rendering.` and you can no longer interact with the components on the page until the page is reloaded.  It works correctly in Firefox and Safari (user is able to interact with components after printing the page, and the error is not present).

What should I do to ensure the state is updated when the user wants to print the page, and have it still be responsive when the print dialog is closed?

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was not in this code, the component also called `updatePrint` in the event handler, and it Chrome it was triggering the event handler more than once.  The second invocation caused the error.